# Aligning icons to select tag

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I'm attempting to make my form pretty I'm not sure what I'm doing. I've got two select boxes and two sets of icons that I would like to format like this:

```
^   +-------------+        +--------------+
|   |             |   <--  |              |
    |  Select 1   |   -->  |  Select 2    |
|   |             |        |              |
v   +-------------+        +--------------+
```

The left and right icons in the middle move items to and from the Select boxes and the up and down arrows on the left move items in Select 1 up and down. Whats an easy to way to get this layout with css? I've been able to hack something together with a table I've had no luck with a pure css solution.

Comment: Post your table solution on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). That way, someone can create something which looks the same but uses CSS for the layout instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- I hadn't seen that site before. Here is what I'm trying to go for: http://jsfiddle.net/rTJHK/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/PWXQc/)

I took the liberty of adding `cursor: pointer` to the buttons. It would be better from a semantic point of view if you changed them from `<img>` tags to `<a>` tags.

I also added `size="4"` to the `<select>` tags to ensure consistent height between different browsers.

I didn't touch the JS.

Tested in IE7/8, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari.

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ccc
}
.buttons {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 0 3px
}
.buttons img {
    cursor: pointer
}
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    width: 160px
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="buttons">
        <img src="http://www.jgrmx.com/cgr/tiles/generic/images/icons/arrow-up.gif" id="up_button"><br>
        <img src="http://www.jgrmx.com/cgr/tiles/generic/images/icons/arrow-down.gif" id="down_button">
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <select multiple=true id="left" size="4">
        <option>Patricia J. Yazzie</option>
        <option>Michael A. Thompson</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <img src="http://www.jgrmx.com/cgr/tiles/generic/images/icons/arrow-left.gif" id="add_button"><br>
        <img src="http://www.jgrmx.com/cgr/tiles/generic/images/icons/arrow-right.gif" id="remove_button">
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <select multiple=true id="right" size="4">
        <option>Kevin C. Bounds</option>
        <option>Patricia J. Yazzie</option>
        <option>Michael A. Thompson</option>
        <option>Mark D. Mercer</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Not cross-browser friendly - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AhRpZ/2/).

```
<style type="text/css">
    .form-wrap div {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left; // makes it work in IE, but breaks it in Firefox
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .form-wrap img { display: block; }
</style>

<div class="form-wrap">
    <div class="buttons-left">
        <img src="http://www.jgrmx.com/cgr/tiles/generic/images/icons/arrow-up.gif" id="up_button">
        <img src="http://www.jgrmx.com/cgr/tiles/generic/images/icons/arrow-down.gif" id="down_button">
    </div>

    <div class="select-left">
        <select multiple=true id="left">
            <option>Patricia J. Yazzie</option>
            <option>Michael A. Thompson</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons-mid">
        <img src="http://www.jgrmx.com/cgr/tiles/generic/images/icons/arrow-left.gif" id="add_button">
        <img src="http://www.jgrmx.com/cgr/tiles/generic/images/icons/arrow-right.gif" id="remove_button">
    </div>

    <div class="select-right">
        <select multiple=true id="right">
            <option>Kevin C. Bounds</option>
            <option>Patricia J. Yazzie</option>
            <option>Michael A. Thompson</option>
            <option>Mark D. Mercer</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/AhRpZ/) a live version of your solution - I was curious to see how well it worked in IE. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in even IE8. Looks bang on in Firefox though.

Comment: Yeah, I rushed my answer when I saw that you had posted one too. :P  Oh well.

Comment: Both answers were spot on -- Thanks a bunch to both of you.