# align icons with 1 or 2 lines of text to top with css

Tags: css, stylesheet, alignment

i have a set of icons, each with 1 or 2 lines of text underneath. i want them to flow next to each other on a page. there is a variable number of icons for each user, so i can't set the number of rows. here's what i have: [click for image](http://vnovos.com/gtmobquestion.png)

now i'm trying to make it so that the icons line up on the horizontal axis, and the text does the same. so even if an item only has 1 line of text, it should have room for two. basically i want to vertically align each item to the top. does that make sense?

i tried various attempts at making the icons vertically align to the top, but nothing worked. any ideas?

here's the basic code:

```
    <div id="menuicons">

    <div class="menuicon"><a href="#"><img class="widget_icon" src="images/icon_buses.png" alt="Buses"></a>
<br><span align="center">Buses</span></div>
    <div class="menuicon"><a href="#"><img class="widget_icon" src="images/icon_bugs.png" alt="Report Bugs"></a>
<br><span align="center">Report Bugs</span></div>
    <div class="menuicon"><a href="#"><img class="widget_icon" src="images/icon_directory.png" alt="The Directory"></a>
<br><span align="center">The Directory</span></div>
    <div class="menuicon"><a href="#"><img class="widget_icon" src="images/icon_places.png" alt="Places"></a>
<br><span align="center">Places</span></div>
    more icons, etc...
    </div>
```

and some css:

```
#menuicons{
    padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}

#menuicons img{
    border:none;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    padding-top:2px;

    height:64px;
}

.menuicon{
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    width:70px;
    overflow:hidden;

    position:relative;
}
.menuicon span{
    display:block;
    width:78px;
    height:2.1em;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788302/aligning-icons-to-select-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/Kxzze/)

Added:

```
.container {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Around groups of 2 elements.

Comment: thanks for the help. how come it has to be around every 2 elements? i tried it with 1 and it was messed up, but i don't understand why.

Comment: It is around two elements as you want one above the other right? So how it works is it groups one and the one next to it, then due to the low width it forces it directly below it, then the groups of two are floated left to allow them to line up nicely side-by-side. Does this help?

Comment: ooohh it's  printing in columns of two isn't it? that's a problem because there's the potential to have many many icons (so there could easily be more than 2 rows). and each user has a different number of icons so i can't predict the number of rows, it just has to work for every possibility.

Comment: yes, JS should be fine. btw each icon is dynamically added using PHP if that matters for anything.

Comment: Do they all have a common size? like 50x50px or anything?

Comment: as wide as the screen will allow. and this will be used in a wide variety of browsers, including mobile browsers. so ideally the number of columns changes depending on the size of the screen, and also if you resize the page.

Comment: So you wouldn't mind if the user's screen was wide enough to have everything all in one line?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/Kxzze/11/ - They don't line up directly underneath each other but resize the window, I think it looks very tidy and is pure CSS.

Comment: thanks for the help. i ended up getting them to line up directly by adding a line break after the span. this forced all items to be at least 2 lines tall, and the 3rd line is hidden because the height is set.

Comment: @vee Sounds like a nice solution, no problems with expansion at all?